Calling Oracle PL SQL Script from C#
it is required from me to upload attachments to Oracle apps r12 EBS through API and link it to Purchase Order. i found the following solution, but i need to know how to implement it on C#.

Upload File
You first upload the file with FNDGFU into FND_LOBS. This is the sample call to FNDGFU passing in the apps user and password, a program name and tag, language, and filename (MyAPIFileName.txt). The call uploads the file into FND_LOBS.  Here is the example call:

$FND_TOP/bin/FNDGFU apps/apps 0 PROGRAM_NAME='FNDATTCH' PROGRAM_TAG='PO' LANGUAGE='US' MyAPIFileName.txt

Link Uploaded File

For linking file to an entity use
fnd_webattch.add_attachment public API.
The API FND_WEBATTCH.add_attachment call creates a record in FND_DOCUMENTS to detail the file contents and link to the file id (via FND_DOCUMENTS.MEDIA_ID). A record is also created in FND_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS that links the item to the file
Best Regards
